# require_once Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php configuration in index.php?

Tags: php, zend-framework, configuration

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->registerNamespace('./application/');
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
```

this is not working for me i.e getinstanc() is not being called but require_once is not throwing any error

I even removed the entire zend folder from library then also it is not throwing error

Answer (score 1):

`require_once` will definitely throw an error if the file isn't there. You probably have display_errors turned off - check your Apache error log for the actual error, and ensure you have APPLICATION_ENV set to 'development' in your dev environment.

Also the namespace you are passing to registerNamespace is not valid, you probably want something more like `$loader->registerNamespace('Application_');`

Comment: i've overcome that error and changed the name space into Hiring_ can you answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331887/zend-framework-model-inclusion-path-configured-perfectly-and-failed-to-load